# "Generator already running" message on any error

Tags: node.js, generator, koa

I have a very simple generator function, like this

```
exports.whatever = function *(next) {
  this.body = 'wow';
  z
};
```

Now, there obviously is a syntax error here ('z' on the third line),
but with koa's generators, the error I get in the console is basically useless for debugging; I do not get the line of the error, the file, or even the type of error. All I get is:

```
Error: Generator is already running
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.next (native)
    at onFulfilled (/Users/johndoe/Documents/nodejs/testing/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:59:19)
    at /Users/johndoe/Documents/nodejs/testing/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:48:5
    at Object.co (/Users/johndoe/Documents/nodejs/testing/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:47:10)
    at Object.toPromise (/Users/johndoe/Documents/nodejs/testing/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:112:63)
    at next (/Users/johndoe/Documents/nodejs/testing/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:93:29)
    at onRejected (/Users/johndoe/Documents/nodejs/testing/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:79:7)
```

Is there any way to see the real detail of the error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add some error-handling middleware.

Comment: Tried that, but it still gives the same error: `[Error: Generator is already running]`

Comment: Can you provide more context?  I made few guesses at the rest of your code, but my simple tests show good error messages ie 'z' not defined with a reference to the file and line #

Comment: Wow, you're right. Trying it for example from main.js gives the correct error. Try putting it inside `app.use(router(app)).get('/', function *(next){ x })` the router module is koa-router